# What's the highest userland address that Windows x64 program can allocate?

Tags: windows, memory-management

I'm curous what is the address of the highest userland memory page that Windows x64 program can allocate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `GetSystemInfo` to determine this -- `SYSTEM_INFO` has a field `lpMaximumApplicationAddress`. In Windows 8 and earlier, the userland address space was 8TB; in Windows 8.1 Preview and later it is 128TB.

Comment: Thanks, found that for 64-bit it is: 
lpMaximumApplicationAddress : 000007FF'FFFEFFFF

Comment: @User: Again, note that this value changes from one version of Windows to the next or from one Service Pack to the next.